# TypeScript, objects and type discrimination

Tags: javascript, typescript

So typescript has something called type discrimination:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/discriminate-types

however, is something like this possible?

```js
type A = {id: "a", value: boolean};
type B = {id: "b", value: string};

type AB = A | B;

const Configs = {
  a: {
    renderer: (data: A)=>{
      // ...
    }
  },
  b: {
    renderer: (data: B)=>{
      // ...
    }
  }
} as const;

const renderElement = (element: AB)=>{
  const config = Configs[element.id];

  const renderer = config.renderer;
  return renderer(element); 
}
```

Currently my last line fails with this message.
I more or less know what it means but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Argument of type 'AB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'A & B' was reduced to 'never' because property 'id' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
```

Longer example
It only shows the idea that I'm working on (I didn't event check if it works, recursive typing is prob wrong too, I didn't learn it yet).

```js
type HeaderProps = { text: string, size: number, color: string};
type ImageProps = { src: string, width: number, height: string};
type GroupProps = { numberOfColumns: number, children: Item[], height: string};

type Item = {
  kind: string,
  data: HeaderProps | ImageProps | GroupProps
}

const itemsConfig = {
  header: {
    onRender: (props: HeaderProps)=>{
      
    }
    // + some other handlers...
  },
  image: {
    onRender: (props: ImageProps)=>{
      
    }
    // + some other handlers...
  },
  group: {
    onRender: (props: GroupProps)=>{

    }
    // + some other handlers...
  }
} as const;

const exampleItemsPartA = [
  {
    kind: 'header',
    data: {
      text: 'Hello world',
      size: 16,
    }
  },
  {
    kind: 'header',
    data: {
      text: 'Hello world smaller',
      size: 13,
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  {
    kind: 'image',
    data: {
      src: 'puppy.png',
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    }
  }
];

const exampleItems = [
  ...exampleItemsPartA,
  {
    kind: 'group',
    data: exampleItemsPartA
  }
]

const renderItems = (items: Item[])=>{
  const result = [];

  for(const item of items){
    const {onRender} = itemsConfig[item.kind];
    result.push(onRender(item.data))
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is the first SO question where I'd have pointed someone to [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and just shrugged, but yesterday [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) was merged to fix it.  If I follow the recommendations there, it converts your code to [this](https://tsplay.dev/wenVXN).  Does that work for you?  If so I can write up an answer explaining how it works.  If not then if you could elaborate on why I'd appreciate it. This is the first real-world test for that "distributive object type" solution. 

Comment: "Does that work for you?" I'm not sure to be honest  I just started learning TS, so I can't tell what is going on in that code, thus I don't know how flexible it is. Maybe I'll explain what I would like to use it for. Imagine that these types A and B describe a state of some component. There could be a lot of these types, and all of them could use completely different set of props. You could provide an array of these configs (various types), and they would be rendered in a loop.

Comment: Only id would be required.

Comment: I think that would be supported but I can't be certain without a [mre].  If you can't map an answer from your example to your intended use case, then maybe your example should be a little more fleshed out?  Anyway I am happy to write up the answer explaining what is going on with that solution, and you don't have to accept it if you can't understand it.

Comment: I've added a longer example.

Comment: So does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyOPxN) work for you?  I had to change some of your things to make it compile (it helps when your [mre] is something you test first so that people don't have to fix typos before they can answer) but it's the same general idea.

Comment: Yes, I think it would work perfectly fine. Thanks for the help :) "so that people don't have to fix typos" that was just a quick draft. I'll change it later, but at least I know that something like this is (will be) possible (since yesterday).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For both your original and extended examples, you are trying to represent something like a "correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type" as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

For example, inside `renderElement`, the `renderer` value is a union of functions, while the `element` value is a union of function arguments.  But the compiler won't let you call `renderer(element)` because it doesn't realize that those two unions are *correlated* to each other.  It has forgotten that if `element` is of type `A` then `renderer` will accept a value of type `A`.  And since it has forgotten the correlation, it sees any call of `renderer()` as [calling a union of functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  The only thing the compiler will accept as an argument is something which would be safe for every function type in the union... something which is *both* an `A` *and* a `B`, or the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `A & B`, which [reduces to `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties) because it's not possible for something to be both an `A` and a `B`:

```
const renderElement = (element: AB) => {
  const config = Configs[element.id];     
  const renderer = config.renderer;
  /* const renderer: ((data: A) => void) | ((data: B) => void) */
  return renderer(element); // error, element is not never (A & B)
}
```

Anyway, in both cases, the *easiest* thing to do is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler not to worry about its inability to verify type safety:

```
  return (renderer as (data: AB) => void)(element); // okay
```

Here you're telling the compiler that `renderer` will actually accept `A` or `B`, whatever the caller wants to pass in.  This is a lie, but it's harmless because you know that `element` will turn out to be the type that `renderer` really wants.

---

Until very recently that would be the end of it.  But [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) was implemented to provide a way to get type-safe correlated unions.  It was just merged into the main branch of the TypeScript code base, so as of now it looks like it will make it into the TypeScript 4.6 release.  We can use nightly `typescript@next` builds to preview it.

Here's how we'd rewrite your original example code to use the fix.  First, we write an object type which represents a mapping between the discriminant of `A` and `B` and their corresponding `data` types:

```
type TypeMap = { a: boolean, b: string };
```

Then we can define `A`, `B`, and `AB` in terms of `TypeMap`:

```
type AB<K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = 
  { [P in K]: { id: P, value: TypeMap[P] } }[K];
```

This is what is being called "a distributive object type".  Essentially we are taking `K`, a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the discriminant values, splitting it up into its union members `P`, and *distributing* the operation `{id: P, value: TypeMap[P]}` over that union.

Let's make sure that works:

```
type A = AB<"a">; // type A = { id: "a"; value: boolean; }
type B = AB<"b"> // type B = { id: "b"; value: string; }
type ABItself = AB // { id: "a"; value: boolean; } | { id: "b"; value: string; }
```

(Note that when we write `AB` without a type parameter, it uses the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `keyof TypeMap` which is just the union `"a" | "b"`.)

Now, for `configs`, we need to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as being of a similarly [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which turns `TypeMap` into a version where each property `K` has a `renderer` property that is a function accepting `AB<K>`:

```
const configs: { [K in keyof TypeMap]: { renderer: (data: AB<K>) => void } } = {
  a: { renderer: (data: A) => { } },
  b: { renderer: (data: B) => { } }
};
```

This annotation is crucial.  Now the compiler can detect that `AB<K>` and `configs` are related to each other.  If you make `renderElement` a generic function in `K`, then the call succeeds because a function accepting `AB<K>` will accept a value of type `AB<K>`:

```
const renderElement = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(element: AB<K>) => {
  const config = configs[element.id];
  const renderer = config.renderer;
  return renderer(element); // okay
}
```

Now there's no error.  And you should be able to call `renderElement` and have the compiler infer `K` based on the value you pass in:

```
renderElement({ id: "a", value: true });
// const renderElement: <"a">(element: { id: "a"; value: boolean; }) => void
renderElement({ id: "b", value: "okay" });
// const renderElement: <"b">(element: { id: "b"; value: string; }) => void
```

---

So that's the gist of it.  For your extended example you can write your types like

```
type ItemMap = { header: HeaderProps, image: ImageProps, group: GroupProps };
type Item<K extends keyof ItemMap = keyof ItemMap> = { [P in K]: { kind: P, data: ItemMap[P] } }[K]
type Whatever = { a: any };
const itemsConfig: { [K in keyof ItemMap]: { onRender: (props: ItemMap[K]) => Whatever } } = {
  header: { onRender: (props: HeaderProps) => { return { a: props } } },
  image: { onRender: (props: ImageProps) => { return { a: props } } },
  group: { onRender: (props: GroupProps) => { return { a: props } } }
};
```

And your `renderItems()` function also needs a slight refactoring so that each `item` can be passed to a generic callback:

```
const renderItems = (items: Item[]) => {
  const result: Whatever[] = [];
  items.forEach(<K extends keyof ItemMap>(item: Item<K>) => {
    const { onRender } = itemsConfig[item.kind];
    result.push(onRender(item.data))
  })
  return result;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20211215#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlMIA2GCiAPcMGyA3gLABQFSSoksCyA8gE4CWA5kmeddQC4BPGMgCCSALxckrACYAuJACIQigDRIAbpgCuEBQCMA9oaIhgSAL4BuKr0HCkAIQlTZCxfrWadepFD5swJzWFLb8QqLOkmIAPk42lDy88IbA-kgAwqkAZhxQLty8vCAKxEjMEMAyEBXMCgAUMiB8JUgiAJQSAHxSFpaqYbz6peWV1bUNTS0Kjp3iPWV9FoPLiUUpaXyjVTXYRJDAW5L1EPuVfAois91cg9Qb6Ru5nJJZwM9QANqnEAd8AHSyAC6CSK91S6QqO1qLieHH+UPGNVBYIA9AAqJAPLaImo1BqNZqtDo3DSGWSdOL1QnTJxzHpkilIdGou6jPjaZjmXG1E5nQ7tKxIVGopA1ZiGZgAQhWoSS4M223Ge1+5xEUCgNSOSD5qsOl2u81u8uSEK2cJemRyeW+-IBwJR6zNSrxzFh1vYCLGrsdvAqHK5Op5NSQIHyNOJhoZ5Jk7V1f0FwtFhgA1iABLK1n7vcwVX96mU3EoVOotBhdAoArpLILBjy8+cC9J5EpPKWfO5U+nFDXbKtbLRoHBEEgACKsfxsfTaPisDQQRj6ABWEHgfAAYqxcMaivZkAAVCIAWRAMAKoYMxlMwHUwz8AVYQUsCUGe7ajgAPABpMW4PhjfIUwgARDGyJBD2EE8z0kICQLAiCICgnpJDKT4AAVpHML8gRGIs0PbctfAQqD0KBSxLE+bDfTfMRok-ZRFC6IURSQGjzyLBihTLCskCMEwIDMIVVl3CInBcK4Pw8Rik1Y0SolcFspK4jt70CdghNfUSrgAST4TUMDAuiZMLRSVGUwjL34wTyLiEz3E8cyeMnR91MsOUnUVC0oBGSjMKQWDQPA49TxwqRgzqHUpkjb8unpTQY3IvoULZVoynCyYiUuOLFn6Nk7zSnN8UizK6RuHLhN4EIswVSEcwbQ4XG-X9-yqQDgMC4jTy6eNzgNGLsrZbEsQ9d13htH4-kBGQQUG51wtG54vWhZE2X9TluUK5geoFX1+xNes7SbDiS28CzWOYasLFrE0WKGg69QuJBJJUbqJt6hT3DM06eL468hLixkZDrOrDrs1svG43xFC7AQeyu31brmkGHoUSTPFeu1cMUhzvt8Zygn+0kY3ctzyD2wd6BHAAZVJ2DwAgiGNAdwCHBgkBYDgdzsUSAAkBPGNCJRgfIUNYiA-wUfH2HUKBWAAL18YBtDAfQanUFIMElSWHyfKqRIcbT0HYCBBcMYXzygZh4G1tT1AAd1kPgAAsFCVlW1aQJ2IA4J3Hql59NIcABxCVtBgU3zdFt3VeYRhsiycswDSV3lZj9WndYDAZChBRdN+T4gXUL2fb9nXghfE03zzsACjZFNHxbKWBhNagooUPmQAFoX8jiQ2QGNiOe6QEPDDDwfMxJ8IHAAdSd5oIHnN1RdaMwBADk0htYf8wCgN5nlrlvPf5oqylSAAlHMGhgbv2+P5hB+y9l1qkVpr7N-Illyw-WCN3xT+AC+0Ir43yQH3Ae3dH5rUDGUV+3dEpfzBEgdgocYAjHPpfHUb9hYKBHmPCBZUn7QIvEgLBH9EorAroMIa4sGYQGrlANCIBmB8BELnbeBcXCfDZIURB-kG4KAAORe07jUARzdeFIDblzCR-4JZIAEXzLAhgkB20lFnMRbIiiywVgoAAjAANnERI4amsIqKDtk7NeIFtBIGyJKY2WxnYTkUJo0miCLBGKKDwxB9cqiCOEeMDRh9W4lW8bw2Rj0FGnE1iotRMg-DoCwKIzxvDtG+F0QAZhSYgjWWt5EVBkAI1xFUigeO4a43xLYBE-37hAIJEipFhMQZba28iYBhxgAIf4MAgj1OMQ7GQzs9EAAZhnZLBMXdgvt3C6NGUgSUqkXJqGKWyEpSAZrVWGoqGhYBCB0O3iLJAXDD7-FOTsvZ9DGHMJEOMppvBKmCOQaPGAfTEFSPOUQS5TCWGrMGECSeWzarQnoS4eoW9fjeVAewoEA1D53WgNoDA2oC4V0QXYt09RN7b3mWBcFO9Oh3Jqlsf+gDxjkUkHi3eHpPh4v+JUkEMlxSShlME0YUBEUAnaVAJ29R0HQjBdvf4UV2jtF+Zs6gUCNrsqRbtPsJMKbDmQOOZy05Zzzk3NuMJb4O5d3fueCJNsXIy3lorVOHtckRX9nrbmBtf6DwtlbQ1QR7aOxdjQM1zAi7eymaXNS699bIFweHOBUcPVxwTsrZO7r3aeqxBnLOOcoX50LkfEuTry4AqrtvKC54AlFR1TUQe6ganG1zna7u6gnlhxwSg+11qp7IGrk1cWLUZBtTgkmsAOaYLtTAtXJC550J+WwiMB5SB8KSJKv208pFEqUX+Zst8s956L3PCvYAa962Aq2JSveHAfI-kfP5XtnaoKhRJRg+opC2G-BIthOKy7-yrs-slQ+eaIoXqAZgkBBb774KNAVAM5gYEKFIfAsp39f5oIAZe69oDy3v0gRAIDL9QNwM-hBxBVbUFSD5eMYB78a3PIfgQyVqGSHofISaKqVDnQfP2RCq5LCb1gA4ZIY5iDCV8L8fI99rywSNNcfwFtgjFExNUcwdR4ytEmr0YYoTJi8nmMsUgaxtj7HIdYhnKALjWVrOoJhsEXGx1CLvvxoognWXCbkVEpRsTJPxKgIkogzBzNgjSXorJCmLWCIKUUvTqzbkVP4fIktdTpOTtpFx6gLTBHtJgJ07pvSIvUAGUMpAsyxkKcmdMpQmX5luilssgLh81kbNo9s-AuzPkHM4WyU5-x6NfOuUF1lJnsNuZCbSJrBymMiDFUUBdFWgXjBBccSlLGC6wpyUjaVj1H0LxqGxo5GzEGUv+Oi7ACAeXNr-ABY9Hbp0wG6nilj-UyquKGp+slSVpAHL3ewGlgr6W+iKBUOb3TtDct5TB-ltLhWitK4DxBZH3sctlZs+FhyeT0JOFVi5vXvkdF9A8fi-xNbsHqO94HvAMRHLuQxUorjFARMUO4MTyiJNZ2KxIxQaSycZfk6yxQFqGfKasaPdTzAHFaecQNyq6gCcqCJ8z0n5PomU7iQkzALmae8LpyahnmSIss5MJKNnBTdPuJWILtkhPpFgjp1bNn8XEs9PYHLxB5jXVK9GSrnLfA2f5YWUV-nBmyLMlZEkVYFggA)

Comment: I had so many problems without `corelated unions`. Nice to have them.

Comment: @captain-yossarian  It's definitely good to have them but I'm a bit worried that it's too complicated for people to get right.  I suppose the TS4.6 release notes will explain how to do it and then I can point to that.